# Is it possible to toggle the pick/axe/hammer swinging action rather than having to hold down the mouse button?

Tags: terraria

When mining large areas continuously (e.g., meteorite or hellstone), destroying a large section of wall, or leveling a forest  my wimpy index finger starts to cry.  Is there any way to switch the mining/bashing/chopping action on and have it continue until switched off?

Comment: Untested, but try holding down alt and clicking, then letting go of alt. Works with Minecraft and the like.

Comment: @TheCommunistDuck: The ALT key is not captured by Terraria...

Comment: @Tom Wijsman: Like I said, untested. It worked in Minecraft at least. (Yes I know terraria is c# and MC is java)

Comment: There are various keyboard macro systems that could probably accomplish what you want, I've used [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com) before, it's very adaptable but requires scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The download link in the other answer was broken, so I whacked together a really simplified AutoHotKey script:

```
; keys for Terraria to simulate MouseDown and mouseUp

SetTitleMatchMode, 1
if WinActive( "Terraria: ") {

PgDn::
NumpadAdd::
 SendInput {LButton down}
 Return

PgUp::
NumpadSub::
 SendInput {LButton up}
 Return
}
```

All it does is turn on mouseDown with a couple of keys, and mouseUp with a couple others.  Note that another way of turning off the sticky-mouseDown is to click the real mouse button.

P.S. pastebin at http://pastebin.com/rb7EX0tM

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9mnEEajD is the newer version of the script

Answer (score 4):

Here is a macro i wrote using autohotkey. It will auto tunnel, auto bridge, and auto hellevator.

Downloads here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hwd9m2gf7854f2m/TerrariaMacro.zip

Comment: slowest hellevator ever?

Answer (score 3):

There is no toggling available, so unless you get someone to write a loader (if legal) this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found anyplace better to put this, and it kind of solves your problem. This is a script for AutoHotkey that builds a bridge. To use it, select your building material and hover your mouse in the space near your character where you want to build, then tap either Ctrl+Alt+A or Ctrl+Alt+D, depending on which direction you want to go. I made this using a stack of 99 Wood Platforms; if you are using something else, it will work, but it might not use a full stack or might run out of the stack before finishing. If you want to tweak this to use a full stack of whatever material, just change the number after "Loop." The higher the number, the longer you build, so if it's too high you will run out of materials and walk off your bridge. Also, don't move your mouse while the script is running or you may end up building in the wrong place or not at all.

```
; Terraria Automatic Bridge Script

^!d::
SendInput {LButton down}
Loop 94
{
    SendInput {d down}
    Sleep 325
    SendInput {d up}
    Sleep 150   
}
SendInput {LButton up}
Return

^!a::
SendInput {LButton down}
Loop 94
{
    SendInput {a down}
    Sleep 325
    SendInput {a up}
    Sleep 150
}
SendInput {LButton up}
Return
```

EDIT: Also, it leaves you very vulnerable as you have no way to cancel the script once it's running, so either wear a Cobalt/Obsidian Shield and good armor, reduce the loop time, or build during the day low enough to not get harpies.